# Run an application from workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

I'm working with a big project with eclipse and WebSphere plugin. Normally, when I run or debug the project from eclipse, the workspace folders where used. But recently I changed something or maybe was an update of eclipse that broke it, I don't know. Now when I run the project it deploys it to a temporary folder and then WebSphere serves it from the temporary folder instead from the workspace.

That breaks every simlink that i have to serve content from out of the workspace.

- Does any one knows why the behavior change in eclipse ?
- Is there    any way to change it back ?
- Is there any alternative solution to
  keep the simlinks in the temporary folder ?

Comment: Maybe you could check your Eclipse "Run Configuration", "Arguments" tab, "Working directory".

Comment: Checking your Error log window might also produce some interesting clues. Look for build issues in particular.

Answer (score 1):

As to why it switched, I have no idea. But for changing it back, if you're describing what I think you are, try double-clicking on the WebSphere server definition (or right-click > Open), and see the section "Publishing settings for WebSphere Application Server":

[image]